# How can we delete icon from QPushButton?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qpushbutton

After begining the program I set icons on all pushbuttons.
Code is like this:

```
QImage img;
img.load(pictureName);    
ui->pushButton_1->setIcon(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
ui->pushButton_1->setIconSize(img.size());
```

But after some actions I need delete pictures and set some text. How can I do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to delete an image you can set an empty image instead of existing one. For example:

```
ui->pushButton_1->setIcon(QIcon());
```